# Exception when starting SQL Server 2012 service from .NET code

Tags: vb.net, wmi, sql-server-2012

I'm attempting to start a SQL Server instance from the following code:

```
Dim computer As New ManagedComputer
Dim pmSQL As ServerInstance = computer.ServerInstances("TheInstance")
```

When I upgraded to SQL Server 2012 this gives the following error:

`SQL Server WMI provider is not available on MACHINENAME.`

With an Inner Exception of:

`Invalid namespace`

Do I need to install something additional on my system? Does this make sense that it worked for pre-2012 but not 2012?

Edit:
I'm using the .dlls from c:\program files\microsoft sql server\100\SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the app was using dlls from a previous version of SQL Server. I updated to the 2012 version and it seems to work well.